# does the last call in 'async' call graph need to be synchronous?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

For example, in the code below, the last method M2Async is synchronous and does not have async/await as otherwise there would need to be a call to M3Async after await and the call graph would continue?

For clarity (from C# in a Nutshell):

- A synchronous operation does its work before returning to the caller.
- An asynchronous operation does (most or all of) its work after returning to the caller.

  public void Main()
  {
      Task task = M1Async();
      // some work
      int i = task.result;
      // use i etc
  }

  private async Task M1Async()
  {
      int i = await M2Async();
      // some work
      return i;
  }

  private Task M2Async()
  {
      return Task.FromResult(2);
  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends a bit on what you mean by "synchronous". In some ways, *all* methods are synchronous (even `async` ones) - they just synchronously return something that can be awaited and which might have more things to do once awaited.

No, it doesn't have to be synchronous; your code could just as well be:

```
private async Task<int> M2Async()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(2);
}
```

or even just (although the compiler will detect that this is a smell, and is secretly synchronous):

```
private async Task<int> M2Async()
{
    return 2;
}
```

Neither of which would be particularly useful, but; they would work. In reality, most `async` methods will bottom out at something that is doing `async` IO - file-system, network, etc. In your example, there is nothing that will actually truly be `async` *anyway* - it will all be completed when the `await` is reached.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'm using the meaning of aysnchronous as now added to my question. Unfortunately my example is contrived, but my point is the last method would usually be synchronous - return await Task.FromResult(2) is synchronous despite having async/await combo, as there is no code to run after it returns.

However, I've now thought of one example of an asynchronous last method - where its code is wrapped in Task.Run().

e.g. private Task<int> M2Async(){Task.Run(()=> ...)};